# Loading PayPal Smart Buttons (JS SDK) with Brave Browser throws errors

Tags: paypal, brave-browser

I'm trying to get a basic PayPal button on my web page, but I can't even load the API without getting errors. I've asked for help on PayPal's own forum, but no one replies.

Here is my page. I'm running in sandbox mode. I've replaced the actual client ID below with [CLIENTID].

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>PayPal test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?debug=true&client-id=[CLIENTID]"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

I can add a button to the page, and make a purchase, so the buying process works. But it always throws this error at page load. I'm on Win10, Brave Browser (based on Chromium).

```
js?debug=true&client…ruzpDLhao-FzS6:2659 unhandled_error 
{err: "Error: Invalid json: .↵    at XMLHttpRequest.<anon…[CLIENTID]:2597:55)", timestamp: "1601234382102", referer: "localhost", uid: "9b7c68f416_mtk6mtc6ntq", env: "sandbox"}
env: "sandbox"
err: "Error: Invalid json: .↵    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?debug=true&client-id=[CLIENTID]:2597:55)"
referer: "localhost"
timestamp: "1601234382102"
uid: "9b7c68f416_mtk6mtc6ntq"
__proto__: Object
```

===============================================================

UPDATE

Sorry, I incorrectly wrote I am on Google Chrome. I'm on Brave Browser (based on Chromium). I've tested on Google Chrome and MS Edge, and it works there. Brave is where the errors happen. I've tried to add a new sandbox app, but get the same error. I've used the Brave browser settings to allow my site all privileges, but still the same error.

Live test:

Just loading API: https://www.trainerslab.app/PayPalTest.html

Example from PayPal dev site: https://www.trainerslab.app/PayPalTest2.html

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I seems as if the `.` could be complaining about possible amount value, that should be in a string, if it is not?  Meaning, if the json looks like this: `"value": 10.99,` should instead look like `"value": "10.99",` Other than that, might need to see a sample json (with sensitive info replaced with dummy values, of course) Might also be a `.` where a separating comma is supposed to be? The comma and period keys are close to each other, so double check that too.

Comment: Please post a full testable sample with either a real sandbox client ID (this is not sensitive information, you can create as many as you need in https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications , or just `client-id=sb`.  Recommended source for demo code: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Comment: Paul T and Preston PHX, thanks for your replies. I've updated the question with more information. It seems it is only related to the Brave browser. Regarding full sample: the code I provided is the full sample. I am simply loading the API, nothing more (minus the ClientID, which I have now provided in the live examples).